# spring mvc annotation jsp page loading error

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, annotations

I can only switch to one of the jsp pages I created. I can not reach the page when I want to upload the others.

package com.ugur.controller like below;

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class ugur {

    @RequestMapping("/javapage")
    public ModelAndView  javapage() {
        ModelAndView model_java = new ModelAndView("javapage");
        return model_java;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/stm")
    public ModelAndView  stm() {
        ModelAndView model_stm = new ModelAndView("stm");
        return model_stm;
    }
}
```

A section from the index.jsp page;

```
    <li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Projects <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="${contextPath}/javapage">JAVA</a></li>
    <li><a href="${contextPath}/stm">STM32</a></li>
```

I can load

> http://localhost:8080/websiteUK/stm

I can NOT load

> http://localhost:8080/websiteUK/javapage

Comment: Did you get any error when you try to load the `/javapage` URL?

Comment: Browser page not found. I did a Debug. Tomcat can not see when I enter the /javapage. But there is no error I confused.